# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery'

Tags: django, docker, redis, pip, celery

I'm sure that I have installed celery using `pip install celery`. I am running my Django application on Docker. When I run the command `docker compose up`, it shows the error.

```
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
batch_email-web-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
batch_email-web-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128, in _find_and_load_unlocked
batch_email-web-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
batch_email-web-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
batch_email-web-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
batch_email-web-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
batch_email-web-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
batch_email-web-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
batch_email-web-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
batch_email-web-1  |   File "/Batch_Email/Batch_Email/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
batch_email-web-1  |     from .celery import app as celery_app
batch_email-web-1  |   File "/Batch_Email/Batch_Email/celery.py", line 4, in <module>
batch_email-web-1  |     from celery import Celery
batch_email-web-1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery'
```

Before installing celery the command `docker compose up` would run the Django server. I have installed Redis for using celery.
Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a file named `celery` which is similar to package named `celery`. Rename your local file to something like `celery_helper.py` or something which is not same as package name.